# How to find list of unique affixes given a list of words?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, trie

An affix can be a prefix (before word), infix (in the middle of a word), or suffix (after word). I have a [list of 200k+ latin/greek names](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/afd70e3a84b8545f5196adafac41b474) used in biological taxonomy. It turns out there is no centralized list of all the affixes used in the taxonomy, *unfortunately*, other than this [very basic list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_commonly_used_taxonomic_affixes).

The question is, how can I take that 200k+ list of latin/greek names, and divide it into a list of affixes (ideally using just plain JavaScript)?

I don't really know where to begin on this one. If I construct a trie, I need to somehow instead test for specific chunks of words. Or if the chunk can be extended, don't include the chunk until we reach a final extension of some sort...

```
const fs = require('fs')
const words = fs.readFileSync(`/Users/lancepollard/Downloads/all.csv`, 'utf-8').trim().split(/\n+/)
const trie = { children: {} }

words.forEach(word => addToTrie(trie, word))

function addToTrie(trie, word) {
  let letters = word.trim().split('')
  let node = trie
  let i = 0
  while (i < letters.length) {
    let letter = letters[i++]
    node = node.children[letter] = node.children[letter] || { children: {} }
  }
  node.isWord = true
}
```

It doesn't need to be exact, like each affix actually means something, it can be dirty (in that, some words mean something, some words don't). But it shouldn't just list every permutation of a word's letters sort of thing. It should include things which are "potential affix candidates", which are **chunks which appear more than once in the list**. This will at least get me partway there, and I can then manually go through and look up the definitions for each of these "chunks". Ideally, it should also tell whether it is a prefix/infix/suffix. Maybe the output is a CSV format `affix,position`.

You can get creative in how this is solved, as without knowing a list of possible affixes *in advance*, we don't know what the exact output should be. This is basically to try and *find* the affixes, as best as possible. If it includes things like `aa-` as a prefix, for example, which is probably a common sequence of letters yet I don't think is an affix, that is fine with me, it can be filtered out manually. But if there are two words (I am making this up), say `abrogati` and `abrowendi`, then `abro` would be a "common prefix", and that should be included in the final list, not `abr`, `ab`, and `a`, even though those are common too. Basically, the longest common prefix. However, if we have the words `apistal` and `ariavi`, we could say that `a` is a common prefix, so our final list would include `a` and `abro`.

To go into slightly more detail, say we have these two words `aprineyanilantli` and `aboneyanomantli`, they have the common prefix `a-`, and the common suffix `-antli`, as well as the infix `-neyan-`, so those should be in the final list.

It doesn't necessarily need to be efficient, as this is only going to run theoretically once, on the 200k+ list. But if it efficient as well, that would be bonus. Ideally though it shouldn't take hours to run, though I am not sure what's possible :)

Another example is this:

```
brevidentata
brevidentatum
brevidentatus
crassidentata
crassidentatum
crassidentatus
```

Here, the first 3 have a common *prefix*, `brevidentat`, then 2-3 have the common prefix `brevidentatu`. But later (with human knowledge), we find `identat` is probably the *infix* we desire, and `a`/`um`/`us` are word form suffixes. Also, we see that `identat` is an infix in the two words `crass...` and `brev...`. So the end result should be:

```
brav-
crass-
-identat-
-a
-us
-um
```

That, in theory, would be the ideal outcome. But you could also have this:

```
brav-
crass-
-identat-
-identata
-identatus
-identatum
```

That would also work, and we could do some simple filtering to filter those out later.

**Note**, I don't care about infixes in the sense of word parts that *surround* something else, like `stufffoo...barstuff`, where `foo...bar` wraps something. I just care about the word parts which are repeated, such as prefixes, suffixes, and stuff in the middle of words.

Comment: Common prefixes can be found in the trie by looking at all vertices with more than one departing edge. Then build a new trie from the first prefix onwards. Continue iteratively, then every affix becomes a prefix.

Comment: @JonasWilms could you show in code, I am going to have difficulty translating that into code.

Comment: How many affixes can there be in one word? Would `b|c-ra-v|ss-identat-|a|us|um` be a valid result? If yes, why is `brav|crass-…` "better"?

Comment: Well after a while, we will probably have lots of two and 3 letter affixes, but those could probably (hopefully) be quickly filtered out by a human. I guess I am looking for the longest potential matches.

Comment: I happened to have had a Latin and modern languages education of 6 years throughout graduate; the first question that comes to mind is what purpose you try to fulfil. I don't remember much of Greek specifically, but in Latin the suffixes you refer to are consequence of different factors; primarily the type (noun, adjective, adverb etc), the role it fulfils (subject, direct object etc), the gender etc. In that sense, prefix and suffix aren't similar and the case of an infix is different altogether. I wouldn't generate suffixes based on a generalized algorithm rather than on grammatical rules.

Comment: Maybe this isn't altogether helpful, but I wonder if the problem can be split up, and if the set of data isn't a shortcoming by itself. Based on what you try to achieve I wonder if what you require is a more solid dictionary to start with that provides you with more parameters. More often than not, the final form of a word is determined by its parameters.

Comment: @html_programmer it would take too much time/money/effort to convert a paperback dictionary (or OCR a PDF) and get out the latin/greek affixes (there is nothing comprehensive already available on the web as far as I've seen). It would also take far too much effort to encode a Latin/Greek parser. By then I would have a natural language understanding machine haha! So I am trying to take a shortcut, and programmatically split the bio taxonomy names into their parts, and then just manually go through the list and find translations for them.

Comment: The goal is to translate the biological taxonomic names into a fantasy language. So for example some Latin/Greek compound word would, in English, maybe become "meat eating plant", which in a fantasy language might become "fooza-barmo-bazni" or "foozabarmobazni". But first I need to know what all the bio word _components_ are, then what they mean, before I can translate them. I can fan-out the workload to many people by creating a list of all the affixes up front, rather than having each person study individual words (often times duplicating effort) and break it apart themselves.

Comment: Seems like a challenge. Not sure if the result of such algorithm will bring you the results you would expect. When skimming through the list I can imagine a lot of pollution with seeming nonsensical results at times. I'm not too convinced that all of these words have actual meaning and some letters may be cut off the base form. Just in case you can't figure it out, you might work in reverse and invent your own plant names based on english. BTW depending on the algorithm you choose, I imagine you want parallel processing, for which js isn't the best fit.

Comment: Since it is only run once, I don't mind about parallel processing even if it takes a while to run. I can try it on a small subset to see at first if it works, then do it on the whole huge list. But JS is my lingo of choice for many reasons, so I am sticking to that.

Comment: Is there no brute force approach which would be able to solve this either?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an interesting problem, and I have a sketch of a solution, with runnable code and somewhat reasonable -- but far from perfect -- output.  It's easy, if not quick, to play with variants.

The idea is to first run through all the words, splitting them in every possible way, then to count the appearances of each prefix, infix, and suffix across all the words, and finally to use that information, together with a scoring function, to choose the best representation of each word.

The scoring functions I've tested involve combinations of the length of the prefix, the count of that prefix across all words, and the same factors for the suffix and affix.  Generally I weigh the lengths much higher than counts, and I focus for now on the prefixes and only slightly weigh the suffixes.

Running this takes a handful of minutes, but more memory than Node gets by default.  I run it as

```sh
node --max-old-space-size=8192 index
```

and that seems to be enough.  I haven't tried it with 4GB.

My code looks like this, with the most recent (and so far my favorite) scoring function:

```js
const {readFile, writeFile} = require ('fs') .promises
 
const range = (lo, hi) =>
  Array .from ({length: hi - lo}, (_, i) => i + lo)
 
const chooseTwo = (n) =>
  range (0, n) .flatMap (i => range (i + 1, n + 1) .map (j => [i, j]))
 
const maximumBy = (fn) => (xs) =>
  xs .reduce ((max, x) => {
    const xScore = fn (x);
    return xScore > max .score ? {score: xScore, val: x} : max;
  }, {score: -Infinity}) .val
 
const breakdown = (word) => {
  const len = word.length;
  const ranges = chooseTwo (len);
  return [
    ... ranges .map (([i, j]) => ({p: word .slice (0, i), i: word .slice (i, j), s: word .slice (j)})),
    ... range (0, len - 1) .map (i => ({p: '', i: word .slice (0, i), s: word .slice (i)})),
  ];
}

const score = (counts) => ({p, i, s}) =>
  Math .max (1, Math .sqrt (1 + counts .prefixes [p]) * p .length ** 2) *
  // Math .max (1, counts .infixes [i] * i .length ) *
  Math .max (1, counts .suffixes [s] * s .length)
 
const process = (words) => {
  const breakdowns = words .map (breakdown)
  const counts = breakdowns .reduce (
    (all, breakdown) => breakdown .reduce (
      (all, {p, i, s}) => {
        all .prefixes [p] = (all .prefixes [p] || 0) + 1;
        all .infixes [i] = (all .infixes [i] || 0) + 1;
        all .suffixes [s] = (all .suffixes [s] || 0) + 1;
        return all;
      },
      all
    ),
    {prefixes: {}, infixes: {}, suffixes: {}}
  )
 
  return breakdowns .map (maximumBy (score (counts)))
}
  
readFile ('./all.csv', 'utf8')
  .then (s => s.split ('\n'))
  .then (process)
  .then (breakdowns => breakdowns .map (({p, i, s}) => `${p ? `(${p}-)` : ''}(${i})${s ? `(-${s})` : ''}`))
  .then (words => writeFile ('./res.csv', words .join ('\n')), 'utf8')
  .then (() => console .log ('Result written'))
```

The first important function is `breakdown`, which, for instance, turns `'horse'` into:

```js
(h)(-orse)
(ho)(-rse)
(hor)(-se)
(hors)(-e)
(horse)
(h-)(o)(-rse)
(h-)(or)(-se)
(h-)(ors)(-e)
(h-)(orse)
(ho-)(r)(-se)
(ho-)(rs)(-e)
(ho-)(rse)
(hor-)(s)(-e)
(hor-)(se)
(hors-)(e)
()(-horse)
(h)(-orse)
(ho)(-rse)
(hor)(-se)
(h-)(orse)
(ho-)(rse)
(hor-)(se)
(hors-)(e)
```

which is stored internally with `p`, `i`, and `s` properties, for `prefix`, `infix`, and `suffix`, so it actually looks like this:

```js
[
  {p: '', i: 'h', s: 'orse'},
  {p: '', i: 'ho', s: 'rse'},
  {p: '', i: 'hor', s: 'se'},
  {p: '', i: 'hors', s: 'e'},
  {p: '', i: 'horse', s: ''},
  {p: 'h', i: 'o', s: 'rse'},
  {p: 'h', i: 'or', s: 'se'},
  {p: 'h', i: 'ors', s: 'e'},
  {p: 'h', i: 'orse', s: ''},
  {p: 'ho', i: 'r', s: 'se'},
  {p: 'ho', i: 'rs', s: 'e'},
  {p: 'ho', i: 'rse', s: ''},
  {p: 'hor', i: 's', s: 'e'},
  {p: 'hor', i: 'se', s: ''},
  {p: 'hors', i: 'e', s: ''},
  {p: '', i: '', s: 'horse'},
  {p: '', i: 'h', s: 'orse'},
  {p: '', i: 'ho', s: 'rse'},
  {p: '', i: 'hor', s: 'se'},
  {p: 'h', i: 'orse', s: ''},
  {p: 'ho', i: 'rse', s: ''},
  {p: 'hor', i: 'se', s: ''},
  {p: 'hors', i: 'e', s: ''},
]
```

`breakdown` is built on two trivial functions: `range` creates an integer range, inclusive on the start, exclusive on the end, so that `range (3, 12)` yields `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]`.  And `chooseTwo` finds all pairs of distinct integers between `0` and `n`.

Our second main function is `process`, which does the algorithm described above using `breakdown` and `maximumBy`, which we use to choose the maximum valued breakdown using the `score` function.  In between, we simply count the parts used.

This is all infrastructure.  The important work is in `score`.  You can alter this in so many ways.  If it wasn't holiday time, I would love to play around with variants of this.  But when you do, you should note that although it's easy to play with a small subset of the data and get reasonable-looking results, that doesn't always scale so reasonable to the complete data.  So you will need to run the full code with various functions.

One thing I would suggest investigating is whether there is a reasonably accurate predictive hyphenating tool for English -- not dictionary-based, but either the result of reasonable first principles or of some machine learning runs.  A good hyphenation decision might help you write a better score function.

If you want to see this in action in a small subset of your data, you can expand the following snippet:

```js
const range = (lo, hi) =>
  Array .from ({length: hi - lo}, (_, i) => i + lo)
 
const chooseTwo = (n) =>
  range (0, n) .flatMap (i => range (i + 1, n + 1) .map (j => [i, j]))
 
const maximumBy = (fn) => (xs) =>
  xs .reduce ((max, x) => {
    const xScore = fn (x);
    return xScore > max .score ? {score: xScore, val: x} : max;
  }, {score: -Infinity}) .val

const breakdown = (word) => {
  const len = word.length;
  const ranges = chooseTwo (len);
  return [
    ... ranges .map (([i, j]) => ({p: word .slice (0, i), i: word .slice (i, j), s: word .slice (j)})),
    ... range (0, len - 1) .map (i => ({p: '', i: word .slice (0, i), s: word .slice (i)})),
  ];
}

const score = (counts) => ({p, i, s}) =>
  Math .max (1, Math .sqrt (1 + counts .prefixes [p]) * p .length ** 2) *
  // Math .max (1, counts .infixes [i] * i .length ) *
  Math .max (1, counts .suffixes [s] * s .length)
 
const process = (words) => {
  const breakdowns = words .map (breakdown)
  const counts = breakdowns .reduce (
    (all, breakdown) => breakdown .reduce (
      (all, {p, i, s}) => {
        all .prefixes [p] = (all .prefixes [p] || 0) + 1;
        all .infixes [i] = (all .infixes [i] || 0) + 1;
        all .suffixes [s] = (all .suffixes [s] || 0) + 1;
        return all;
      },
      all
    ),
    {prefixes: {}, infixes: {}, suffixes: {}}
  )
 
  return breakdowns .map (maximumBy (score (counts)))
}

const words = ["cristata", "cristatella", "cristatellidae", "cristatellus", "cristaticeps", "cristaticollis", "cristatiforme", "cristatifrons", "cristatigena", "cristatipes", "cristatispinosa", "cristatissimus", "cristatogobius", "cristatoides", "cristatolabra", "cristatopalpus", "cristatula", "cristatum", "cristatus", "cristavarius", "cristellaria", "cristeremaeus", "cristi", "cristianalemani", "cristiani", "cristibrachium", "cristicauda", "cristiceps", "cristicola", "cristicollis", "cristidigitus", "cristifer", "cristifera", "cristiferus", "cristiformis", "cristifrons", "cristigera", "cristiglans", "cristiloba", "cristimanus", "cristina", "cristinae", "cristipalpis", "cristipes", "cristirhizophorum", "cristis", "cristispira", "cristiverpa", "cristobal", "cristobala", "cristobalensis", "cristobalia", "cristoides", "cristonothrus", "cristophylla", "cristovalensis", "cristovaoi", "cristula", "cristulata", "cristulatum", "cristulatus", "cristuliflora", "cristulifrons", "cristulipes", "cristulum", "cristus", "crisulipora", "critchleyi", "critesion", "crithagra", "crithionina", "crithmifolia", "crithmoides", "critho", "crithodium", "crithopyrum", "critica", "criticum", "criticus", "critola", "critolaus", "critomolgus", "criton", "critonia", "crittersius", "crius", "crivellarii", "crnobog", "crnri", "croasdaleae", "croatanensis", "croatania", "croatanica", "croatica", "croaticum", "croaticus", "croatii", "crobylophorus", "crobylura", "crocaceae", "crocale", "crocallata", "crocallis", "crocana", "crocanthemum", "crocata", "crocatum", "crocatus", "crocea", "croceareolata", "crocearia", "croceata", "croceater", "croceator", "croceatus", "croceguttatus", "croceibacter", "croceicauda", "croceicincta", "croceicoccus", "croceicollis", "croceicornis", "croceiflorus", "croceipennis", "croceipes", "croceitalea", "croceitarsis", "croceithorax", "croceiventre", "croceiventris", "croceoida", "croceoides", "croceoinguinis", "croceola", "croceolanata", "croceomaculatus", "croceopodes", "croceosignatus", "croceovittata", "croceovittatus", "croces", "croceum", "croceus", "croci", "crociaeus", "crocias", "crocidema", "crocidium", "crocidolomiae", "crocidopoma", "crocidura", "crocidurae", "crocidurai", "crocidurinae", "crociduroides", "crocidurus", "crocifera", "crocigrapha", "crocina", "crocinae", "crocineus", "crocinitomix", "crocinopterus", "crocinosoma", "crocinubia", "crocinum", "crocinus", "crocisa", "crocisaeformis", "crockerella", "crockeri", "crockeria", "crockeriana", "crockerinus", "crockettorum", "crococephala", "crocodila", "crocodilensis", "crocodili", "crocodilia", "crocodilichthys", "crocodilinus", "crocodill", "crocodillicola", "crocodilorum", "crocodilosa", "crocodilurus", "crocodilus", "crocodyli", "crocodylia", "crocodylidae", "crocodylus", "crocogaster", "crocolita", "croconota", "croconotus", "crocopeplus", "crocopygia", "crocopygius", "crocorrhoa", "crocosema", "crocosmia", "crocosmiiflora", "crocostethus", "crocota", "crocothemis", "crocotia", "crocotila", "crocoturum", "crocotus", "crocro", "crocus", "crocusella", "crocuta", "crocutasis", "crocutella", "crocynia", "crocyniaceae", "croeciclava", "croeseri", "croesia", "croesioides", "croesus", "croftia", "croftiae", "croftii", "croftoni", "croftus", "crogmaniana", "croicensis", "croilia", "croisseti", "croix", "croizati", "croizatii", "crokeri", "cromagnonensis", "crombiei", "crombota", "cromeria", "cromerus", "cromileptes", "cromion", "cromis", "cromwellii", "cromyorhizon", "cronadun", "cronartiaceae", "cronartium", "cronebergi", "cronebergii", "croni"]
 
Promise .resolve (words)
  .then (process)
  .then (breakdowns => breakdowns .map (({p, i, s}) => `${p ? `(${p}-)` : ''}(${i})${s ? `(-${s})` : ''}`))
  .then (words => console .log (words .join ('\n')))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

The format I use to display these is slightly different than suggested, as I wanted to allow for versions without prefixes or without suffixes but still be quite readable and unambiguous.  Thus `(crist-)(atellid)(-ae)` should be quite clear.  Each of the three sections is surrounded by parentheses.  The prefix ends with a hyphen and the suffix begins with one.  This is the format in the output file, but it would be trivial to change that -- just adjust the function supplied to `breakdowns .map ()` in the last block.

---

A fascinating problem, and I hope I get some time next week to look at it more carefully.

Comment: This looks wonderful! Your code is so concise, it is a little hard for my mind to grok, so I will have to take some time on this. If you do come back and improve in it, that would be even more wonderful :) Going to mark this as the answer for now unless someone else comes along and shifts the waters even further!

Comment: I'll try to look further, because I find this problem fascinating.  But it definitely won't be today.  I did notice duplication in the breakdown of "horse".  That should be fixable with some change to the arguments passed to `range`.  But much more interesting is how to write a note accurate scoring function.

Comment: @Bergi: thanks for the edit.  I generally prefer to code with expressions over statements, but sometimes I carry it too far.

Comment: I spent some time with hyphenation tools and algorithms, but they seem to be based on more common English words than these technical ones and I didn't find any way to use them to improve this.  I still think we might be able to do so on first principles, but don't particularly have the linguistic skills to find an appropriate heuristic.

Comment: Got `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'p' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.`. Filtering those out it works great! Though doesn't give what I was hoping for, unfortunately haha, it was an impossible task! Any ideas how to have it give more what you'd expect? For example, it does (ac-)(idophil)(-us), instead of having that be a whole thing.

Comment: I didn't see that.  I had not run again after Bergi's (probably appropriate) code edit, but it looks as though it introduced some issue.   Try again with [the older version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/70469748/1).  I have played around with  other scoring functions but not gotten anything fantastic.  I think some first principles involving hyphenation and prefixes would help, but I'm not sure what that entails.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple approach, but it is probably in the hours period.  Also, you could do it in JavaScript, but I'll take a generally Unixy approach that you could write in any language because that is simple to think about.

First, let's take your file, and add markers to the start/end of each word, and spaces between the letters.  So your example would become:

```
^ b r e v i d e n t a t a $
^ b r e v i d e n t a t u m $
^ b r e v i d e n t a t u s $
^ c r a s s i d e n t a t a $
^ c r a s s i d e n t a t u m $
^ c r a s s i d e n t a t u s $
```

This is our general representation, space separated possible affixes.  With the basic affixes being letters, begin, and end.  Here we have, of course, found no affixes.

---

Here is what a single affix search pass looks like.

Take our file, and create `tempfile` of the distinct possible affix sections, followed by the line number of the word.  (I say distinct so that if line `666` contains `a b a b` you don't get `a b: 666` twice.) So our file starts off:

```
 ^ b: 1
 ^ b r: 1
 .
 .
 .
 ^ c r a s s i d e n t a t u s $: 6
```

Next we `sort` the file (just use the Unix `LC_ALL=C sort tempfile > sortedtempfile` command, the `LC_ALL` forces asciibetical sort).  You now generate `sortedtempfile` which starts off:

```
 ^ b: 1
 ^ b: 2
 .
 .
 .
 ^ c r a s s i d e n t a t u s $: 6
```

Next run a custom command to give for each prefix that appears at least, say, 2 times, how many symbols you save using this as an affix, followed by the affix, followed by a list of lines where it appears.  This generates a file `tempsaved` that starts off:

```
 3: ^ b: 1 2 3
 6: ^ b r e: 1 2 3
 .
 .
 .
 16: v i d e n t a t u: 2 3
```

Now do `sorted -rn tempsaved > sortedtempsaved` to sort from maximum savings to find the biggest savings first.  This file now starts off

```
 36: ^ c r a s s i d e n t a t: 4 5 6
 33: ^ b r e v i d e n t a t: 1 2 3
 36: ^ c r a s s i d e n t a: 4 5 6
```

In the next function, we identify affixes until we encounter 2 on the same line number.  Then go back to our original file and apply those.  So in this pass we'd identify `^crassidentat` and `^brevidentat`.  Then produce a new file which contains:

```
^brevidentat a $
^brevidentat u m $
^brevidentat u s $
^crassidentat a $
^crassidentat u m $
^crassidentat u s $
```

Now repeat.

---

In your example you'll wind up with the following set of affixes:

```
^crassidentat
^brevidentat
um$
us$
a$
```

If you added the words `identata`, `identatum` and `identatus` to the original list, the same algorithm would generate the following list of affixes instead

```
identat
^crass
^brev
um$
us$
a$
```

which is your stated ideal outcome.

---

My back of the envelope says that you should expect each pass to take several minutes. But we try to find lots of affixes per pass.  So I wouldn't expect this to take more than a few dozen passes.  Also the list will need human review afterwards.  I don't think that there is much avoiding that.

Comment: Seems to me like the question is whether an infix is really an infix or rather a prefix/suffix exposed by the removal of a prefix/suffix. True infixes are fairly rare in real languages, although there are sporadic examples; for some English speakers, the classic (rather informal) case is f...king, which can be infixed for emphasis in certain words at certain locations according to rules which are not so easy to grasp for 2nd language speakers. Those are rarely written, though, and the formal infixes are mostly exposed suffixes or prefixes, which are somewhat easier to identify.

Comment: @rici You got me curious.  They may be rare, but according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasal_infix, ancient Greek is one of the languages that has them.

Comment: iirc, turkish has/had them, too. But in this particular case, my guess is that it's safe to ignore the possibility and work on iterative application of suffix/prefix detection.

Comment: Agglutinative languages like Inuktitut, with which I have more familiarity, allow words to effectively be decomposed into morpheme sequences. Some morphemes are rarely or never discovered at the edges of the word, but they can still be analysed iteratively. Like Gaelic, there are phonetic rules which modify the morphemes when agglutinated, making precise morpheme extraction a bit more challenging, particularly for short morphemes. That process probably is relevant here although the rules are less complicated.

Comment: I have no evidence that prefix/suffix discovery is not enough.  Proto-IndoEuropean had infexes, which survived into both Latin and ancient Greek.  But I don't think that they were common, and even if they were, after stripping off a prefix or two, they become discoverable prefixes.

Comment: Oh I must have gotten confused about "infixes", I didn't mean surrounding word parts like `f...king`, I meant stuff that is inside the word like reconstruction, "construct" is inbetween re- and -ion. So just looking for prefixes, suffixes, and stuff in the middle of words which is repeated across words.

Answer (score 0):

Prefixes and Suffixes are easy with a Trie.  However, a Trie won't help you with infixes.

**Sample code for Trie (in Java, untested, incomplete)**

```
class Node {
    private int cnt;
    private Map<Character, Node> children;

    Node() {
        cnt = 0;
        this.children = new HashMap<>();
    }

    Node(String s, int pos) {
        this();
        addChild(s, pos);
    }

    bool isLeaf() {
        return this.children.size() == 0
    }

    void addChild(String s, int pos) {
        if (pos == s.length()) {
            return;
        }

        char c = s.charAt(pos);
        if (children.containsKey(c)) {
            children.get(c).addChild(s, pos + 1);
        } else {
            children.put(c, new Node(s, pos + 1));
        }
        cnt++;
    }

    void removeChild(char c) {
        int ccnt = 0;
        Node child = children.remove(c);
        if (child != null) {
            ccnt = child.cnt;
        }
        cnt -= ccnt;
    }

    // other methods as necessary for traversal/value lookup...
}

class Solution {
    private Node preroot = new Node();
    private Node sufroot = new Node();

    void addWord(String s) {
        preroot.addChild(s, 0);
        sufroot.addChild(new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString(), 0);
    }

    void findPrefixes(int minOccur) {
        // standard tree traversal on preroot,
        // starting at the left-most leaf.
        // when it finds a non-leaf with cnt >= minOccur
        // output all permutations and remove the child.
    }
}
```

**Infixes**

The problem with infixes is that you don't know where to start.
i.e. take the strings abcdefgh and pppbcdefgzzzz, which have the common infix bcdefg.  furthermore, how about abcdefgh and pppabcdefgzzz?

To solve this, you'll basically need to chop the words into all of its possible constituents, and point back to the word.
Then iterate through the list of chops, sorted by descending length, and remove all entries associated with "used" words.

i.e. abc would become the lookup entries: abc, ab, bc, a, b, c.
Then a lookup table would look like:

Word association to symbols:

```
{abc -> {abc, ab, bc, a, b, c}}
```

Map:

```
{abc -> { abc }}
{ab -> { abc }}
{bc -> { abc }}
{a -> { abc }}
{b -> { abc }}
{c -> { abc }}
```

when we add bcd, which adds the symbols: bcd, bc, cd, b, c, d, the word association is added and the lookup table gets updated:

```
{abc -> { abc }}
{bcd -> { bcd }}
{ab -> { abc }}
{bc -> { abc, bcd }}
{cd -> { bcd }}
{a -> { abc }}
{b -> { abc, bcd }}
{c -> { abc, bcd }}
{d -> { bcd }
```

Then use the length of the key for the map to dictate the sort order.  Starting from the top, navigate until minimum occurrences is reached and then use the words in that list and remove the words from the construct.  Removing the word from the map uses the word association saved earlier to look up the keys in the symbols map.

Comment: Did you try this code with the full example?  I know that when I tried my first idea, I ran out of memory and went heavily into swap.  That is WHY I began using external sorts.

Comment: I didn't write the entire solution above, because I didn't write all of the code in the first place.  I did use a similar technique to address a different problem in my line of work though.  As for memory concerns, that depends on how much input data there is.  200k words isn't a lot of input data, so I don't expect it to exceed ram and require swap (my problem had around 1m strings @ 13 - 19 char length and worked with Xmx set to 4G).  The in-fix solution will require lots of space, so will require use of disk/db.

Comment: The problem I was solving was to find "longest prefix matches" from the input list to an arbitrary input in realtime, requiring near instant (latency in nanoseconds) lookup.  4G was my regular setting, so I don't know if this solution only took Mbs of memory or Gbs of memory.